# sum of rows maximum and minimum is not correct. whats the issue?

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I have a C program. I calculated the sum of each row of array and then compared them to find which row is minimum sum and which is maximum sum. But my program sometimes give correct output but sometime wrong. Where is the issue? please help me. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


///////Prototypes of functions
void displayMaxMinElement(int array[10][10]);
void fillBoard(int array[10][10]);
void rowSum(int array[10][10]);
void displayBoard(int array[10][10]);


/////Starting main function
main() {

    int board[10][10] = {0};      

    system("cls"); ///To clear previous data on screen
    fillBoard(board);
    displayBoard(board);
    displayMaxMinElement(board);        
    rowSum(board);  

    system("pause>nul");    ///Pausing the program without printing "Press any key to continue"
} 


void displayMaxMinElement(int array[10][10]) {
    int max = 0, min = 100;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {

            if(array[i][j] <= min)
                min = array[i][j];

            if(array[i][j] >= max)
                max = array[i][j];
        }
    }    
    cout<<"\n\nArray element with maximum value: "<<max<<endl;
    cout<<"Array element with minimum value: "<<min<<endl<<endl;    
}

void fillBoard(int array[10][10]) {
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            array[i][j] = rand()%100+1;
        }    
    }
}   

void rowSum(int array[10][10])
{
     int maxRow=0, minRow=10000;
     int minRowNo, maxRowNo;
     int sum[10]={0};


     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
             for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                     sum[i]=sum[i]+array[i][j];
                    /// cout<<endl<<sum[i]<<"="<<sum[i]<<"+"<<array[i][j];


             }

     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
             {

                    if(sum[i]<=minRow){
                                   minRow=sum[i];
                                   minRowNo=i;
                                   }
                    else if(sum[i]>=maxRow){
                                   maxRow=sum[i];
                                   maxRowNo=i;
                                   }

                  /// cout<<endl<<"*********"<<sum[i];


              }
     cout<<endl<<"Row"<<minRowNo<<"is minimum and having sum of"<<minRow;
     cout<<endl<<"Row"<<maxRowNo<<"is maximum and having sum of "<<maxRow;

}



void displayBoard(int array[10][10]){
    int *ptr = *array;  

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {       
        cout<<*ptr<<"\t";       
        ptr++;

        if(i%10 == 0) 
            cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    ptr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: its running but with some logical or hidden error

Comment: This is clearly C++, not C, and it should be `int main()`

Comment: is that `else if` correct in `rowSum()`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Whats wrong with `else if`?

Comment: you should provide the input for which your program gives wrong output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With stl, your code may be

```
void rowSum(const int (&array)[10][10])
{
    int sum[10] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sum[i] = std::accumulate(std::begin(array[i]), std::end(array[i]), 0);
    }
    auto p = std::min_max_element(std::begin(sum), std::end(sum));
    std::cout << std::endl << "Row" << std::distance(std::begin(sum), p.first) << "is minimum and having sum of" << *p.first;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Row" << std::distance(std::begin(sum), p.second) << "is maximum and having sum of "<< *p.second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             else if(sum[i]>=maxRow){
```

should just be

```
             if(sum[i]>=maxRow){
```

Because finding `min` and `max` values are independent.

For example, if `minRow` is `1000` and `sum[i]` is `2000` then `2000` is not eligible for *min* value. But it can be a candidate for *max* value.

Comment: thanks. I removed 'else' and now working fine.. .thanks

Answer (score 0):

What looks like is happening is that in `rowSum`, When you're giving the row values to minRow and maxRow, you're using an `else if()` statement.

```
else if(sum[i]>=maxRow){
```

This is a problem because if the sums are in descending order, your program will constantly give minRow a new value, but never assign anything to maxRow.

Of course, this can give correct answers if the sums are in a particular order, but the results won't be consistent.